# Demuxing audio and video

Tags: android, mediamuxer, mediaextractor

I want to demux audio and video from a video file. Is there a way to do that without using any 3rd party libraries like FFMEPG. In all the questions and answers I saw in stack overflow, FFMPEG is recommended. But I want to do it without using that. Any solution is appreciated. thank you.